# AppWidgets on AppWidgetHost disappearing after reboot

Tags: java, android, android-source, android-appwidget

Now this is an unconventional method for using AppWidgets. I'm working in the system level in AOSP. Basically the AppWidgets have a custom widget category that I poll to get the Providiers and everything I need. Now the issue is twofold: 1.) The AppWidgets do not update like they should and 2.) They disappear after reboot and don't show up in the widget list anymore. This also happens when I set the category to be a launcher widget as well(when the service isn't running, launcher widgets work as expected). I can provide logs and stack traces where possible and do anything to help figure this out. I'm tearing my hair out with this. The code for the AppWidgetHost is below.

Notes: 
- I can't use the Settings intents to select AppWidgets, because I need a custom picker.

```
public class SecondScreenService extends Service {

private ArrayList<View> ssas = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Integer> appWidgetIds = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<AppWidgetProviderInfo> secondScreenWidgets = new ArrayList<>();
private FrameLayout fakeRootView;
private SecondScreenView rootView;
private ViewsPagerAdapter viewsPagerAdapter;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private WindowManager wm;
private DisplayManager dm;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private AppWidgetManager mAppWidgetManager;
private AppWidgetHost mAppWidgetHost;
private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new PackageReceiver();
private ArrayList<Integer> pos = new ArrayList<>();
private int scrollState;
public static final int APPWIDGET_HOST_ID = 3254;
public static final String TAG = "BLUG";

private final IBinder mBinder = (IBinder) new LocalBinder();                                                                                              

public class LocalBinder extends Binder {                                                                                                                
    public SecondScreenService getService() {                                                                                                            
        return SecondScreenService.this;                                                                                                                  
    }                                                                                                                                                    
}                                                                                                                                                        

@Override                                                                                                                                                
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {                                                                                                                    
    return mBinder;                                                                                                                                      
}                                                                                                                                                        

@Override                                                                                                                                                
public void onCreate() {                                                                                                                                  
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    wm = (WindowManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

    fakeRootView = (FrameLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_screen_root, null);

    rootView = (SecondScreenView) fakeRootView.findViewById(R.id.secondscreenview);

    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
            PixelFormat.OPAQUE);

    params.privateFlags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.PRIVATE_FLAG_SECOND_SCREEN;
    params.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;
    params.x = 400;
    params.y = 0;
    params.width = 1040;
    params.height = 160;

    wm.addView(fakeRootView, params);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) fakeRootView.findViewById(R.id.second_screen_viewpager);
    viewsPagerAdapter = new ViewsPagerAdapter(this);
    viewPager.setAdapter(viewsPagerAdapter);

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED);
    intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED);
    intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED);
    intentFilter.addDataScheme("package");

    registerReceiver(mReceiver, intentFilter);
    mAppWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
    mAppWidgetHost = new AppWidgetHost(this, SecondScreenService.APPWIDGET_HOST_ID);
    mAppWidgetHost.startListening();
    pollWidgets();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mAppWidgetHost.stopListening();
    if (fakeRootView != null) {
        wm.removeView(fakeRootView);
        fakeRootView = null;
    }
}

private void pollWidgets() {
    for(View view : ssas) {
        mAppWidgetHost.deleteAppWidgetId(((AppWidgetHostView) view).getAppWidgetId());
    }
    ssas.clear();
    int appWidgetId = this.mAppWidgetHost.allocateAppWidgetId();
    List<AppWidgetProviderInfo> widgets = new ArrayList<>();
    mAppWidgetManager.getInstalledProviders(AppWidgetProviderInfo.WIDGET_CATEGORY_SECOND_SCREEN);
    widgets.addAll(mAppWidgetManager.getInstalledProviders(36864));
    for(AppWidgetProviderInfo awpi : widgets) {
        System.out.println("BLUG: SysUI: got widget " + awpi.provider.toString());
        mAppWidgetManager.bindAppWidgetId(appWidgetId, awpi.provider);
        AppWidgetHostView hostView = mAppWidgetHost.createView(this, appWidgetId, awpi);
        hostView.setAppWidget(appWidgetId, awpi);
        ssas.add((View) hostView);
    }
    if(this.viewPager != null && this.viewsPagerAdapter != null) {
        viewsPagerAdapter = new ViewsPagerAdapter(this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(viewsPagerAdapter);
    }
}

private class PackageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                SecondScreenService.this.pollWidgets();
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
}

private class ViewsPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ViewsPagerAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {
        View view = (View) SecondScreenService.this.ssas.get(position);
        collection.addView(view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view) {
        collection.removeView((View) view);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return SecondScreenService.this.ssas.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return "";
    }
}
}
```